# # in url always displays the home page before showing its corresponding contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

Say, [www.example.com#something](http://www.example.com#something) .

This always shows www.example.com briefly before loading the www.example.com#something when i reload www.example.com#something.

In need of a solution please.

```
$(".trending-menu").die().live('click', function()
    {
        $(document).hide();
        var trendingLink = (trendingInfo && trendingInfo.trendingLink ? trendingInfo.trendingLink : '');
        window.location = nonsecure_url + "/index.html#" + trendingLink;
        $(document).show();
        $('.cls_ftd_Invisible_Mask').trigger('click');
        Utils.trackOmniture(false, "Trending Products");
    });
```

Comment: That's just the way browsers work. They start displaying the page as soon as they get content. They can't scroll down to the `something` ID if they haven't received it yet.

Comment: Is there a way to overcome it, say by navigating to that page instead of using # ?

Comment: If there's a hash present you could hide everything else first and then show when appropriate.

Comment: You could hide the body with CSS, and then have Javascript show it after everything is loaded.

Comment: @user2400480 you may also use $(window).bind("load", function() {} to stop jquery till the page is completely loaded. This may hide the page